# Excel Userform not initialising after first load

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook which has multiple layers of userforms.

When the workbook is opened the user is presented with a userform which has two command buttons, one which selects a worksheet with pivottable and slicers and a second which opens another userform containing eight command buttons, seven of which call further individual userforms and the eight which is a close button.

The issue I have is that when I select the command button which opens a new userform, then close the second userform and then reselect the command button to reopen the second userform, the second userform appears but none of the command buttons work nor the close window (X).

The code behind the first command button is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmd_manageAbsence_Click()
    splashScreen.Hide
    Load managementFunctions
    managementFunctions.Show
End Sub
```

The close and terminate code on the second userform is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmd_close_Click()
    Unload managementFunctions
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Sheets("Front").Activate
    splashScreen.Show
End Sub
```

I am having the same issues with the second layer of userforms, but I guess if I get the first layer sorted I can apply the fix to the rest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
Unload Me
```

instead of

```
Unload managementFunctions
```

Also, you might want to look at the difference between `Form.Show` and `Form.ShowDialog` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=vs.71%29.aspx ... i realise this is an old page, but the info is still valid!)

---

Furthermore, you might also benefit from creating your form objects as follows:

```
Dim frm as managementFunctions
set frm = new managementFunctions
frm.Show
```

and then you can use

```
Me.Hide
```

instead of `Unload Me`

Comment: Additionally, OP could call the `Initialize` event programmatically i.e., `Call MyUserForm.UserForm_Initialize()`.  Usually the UF is only *initlialized* once, and after it's been initialized, until it is unloaded when you re-show it, it raises the `Activate` event.  For most ordinary use-cases, the `Activate` event is probably preferable to `Initialize`  -- IOW if OP need to re-populate the form's controls each time it's displayed, use the `Activate` event, because it raises every time the form is shown.

Comment: Sorted, @3-14159265358979323846264. Couldn't use showdialog but the `Dim frm As New managementFunction` method was the clincher. Thanks